# adding a function after the div tag is loaded

Tags: jquery, html

if i have a div tag say

```
<div id="main" style="display:none"></div>
```

its contents are displayed after user clicks on a button.
I have an image which is loaded inside the `"#main"` div tag

```
<img src="a.png" id="tu" />
```

When user clicks on the image some function has to be done
This function has to be loaded after the div tag is loaded, so for that i thought of doing

```
$("#main").load(function() { 

    $('#tu').click(function() {
    alert("asd");
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: DIVs don't have any onload event and onload event doesn't bubble

Comment: ^^ What the Wolff said, the DIV is loaded right away, there is no load event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just delegate click event of image, using closest static container. Without seeing relevant code, i bet `#main` is the closest static container:

```
$('#main').on('click', '#tu', function(){
    alert("asd");
});
```

Otherwise, you could still delegate it to `document` level:

```
$(document).on('click', '#tu', function () {
    alert("asd");
});
```

Using delegation, you don't need to set it after image has been added, you can set it when `#main` is available in DOM (1) or at anytime if using `document` (2).

Answer (score 0):

Change `<img src="a.png" id="#tu" />` to `<img src="a.png" id="tu" />`

Comment: sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is already available when the document load completes then why don't you just do:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tu').click(function() {
        alert("asd");
    });
});
```

In the case where you load your image when your `#main` becomes visible, then you can attach the handler at that point of time, doing something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#someButton').click(function() {
        $("#main").append('<img src="a.png" id="tu" />');
        $('#tu').click(function() {
            alert("asd");
        });

        $("#main").show();
    });
});
```